# Parse using cloudwatch metric filter for access log for a column which has response time and convert it to a metric

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I have access log how can I create cloudwatch metric using cloudwatch metric filter for 0.021 or 0.016. These values are response times. How would I parse and filter this to convert it to a graph

```
api.mydomain.com xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [06/Sep/2020:23:30:57 +0000] "GET /documents/F3VX5A5X3X4Y HTTP/1.1" 200 2616 "-" "axios/0.18.1" "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" 0.021 0.016 . ucs="EXPIRED"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 metric filters, one for each value. Use this filter pattern in both metric filters:

```
[..., response_time_1, response_time_2, dot, ucs]
```

Then in one filter set `$response_time_1` as metric value, and set  `$response_time_2` in the other.

Now you'll have 2 metrics to graph.

See here for more details on metric filters: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html